# data are between parenteses in a query

Tags: python, django

I ve done a query to add values of a data set to be added to another table. query works fine but when adding data in Group table, data are like this: ('Autres dépenses',)
But i just want to have: Autres dépenses. Why there is ( and , and ' characters in ?

this is my code:
def add_group_fromcoa(request):  # add type and subtype of chart of account as first serie of group and subgroup

```
# ------ Type adding -----
types = ChartOfAccount.objects.order_by().values_list("field_type").distinct()

for type_types in types:

    upload_data = Group.objects.get_or_create(group_name=type_types,)
```

print(types) give me that:

```
<QuerySet [{'field_subtype': 'Compte chèques'}, {'field_subtype': 'Fonds en caisse'}, {'field_subtype': 'Comptes clients (CC)'}, {'field_subtype': 'Fonds non déposés'}, {'field_subtype': 'Provision pour créances irrécouvrables'}, {'field_subtype': 'Autres actifs à court terme'}, {'field_subtype': 'Autres immobilisations'}, {'field_subtype': 'Comptes fournisseurs (CF)'}, {'field_subtype': 'Passif à court terme'}, {'field_subtype': 'Impôts à payer'}, {'field_subtype': 'Compte d’attente pour la TPS/TVH'}, {'field_subtype': 'Autres passifs à long terme'}, {'field_subtype': 'Capitaux propres'}, {'field_subtype': 'Capital d’apport ou surplus'}, {'field_subtype': 'Action ordinaire'}, {'field_subtype': 'Actions privilégiées'}, {'field_subtype': 'Bénéfices non répartis'}, {'field_subtype': 'Capital d’ouverture'}, {'field_subtype': 'Autres revenus primaires'}, {'field_subtype': 'Revenu de service/frais'}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `flat` argument to [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

> If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples.

```
.values_list("field_type", flat=True)
```